# MATLAB: wat is the shortest way to display a string and a variable on 1 line?

Tags: string, matlab, variables

I'm know this question has been asked a lot, but i see different answers everywhere.
I'm trying to display a string and a variable on the same line.
I know there are several ways to do it, like with num2str or first creating a string and then display that string. 
But can anyone tell me the shortest/simplest way to achieve this?
Creating a string and then display that string seems a bit devious..

I need to do it many times so it would be nice if i could display multiple lines where each line contains some text and a variable.
Can you do it like `echo"the answer is $var";` like in PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `disp(['the answer is ' num2str(var)])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to learn now fprintf works.

```
fprintf ( 'string and format specifier like %d or %f\n', value, anotherValue )
```

fprintf is powerful and a lot faster than other methods

See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html for examples of how to format the string.

Another useful feature is to write

```
fprintf ( 2, 'using fprintf in this way writes text in red\n' )
```

Comment: Thank you. I came across fprintf a while ago, but i don't understand how it works and how to use it.(i cant find a guide on the web either) What are those %d and %f\n parameters, and the words after the comma's? Could you kindly shortly explain how it works?

Comment: In this example %d means write an integer, %f is a float. \n is a new line. The two words after the comma is variables, i.e an integer and a double. The methodology is the same as sprintf. fprintf is used to write to the terminal or a file. In this example it writes to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so the values between comma's are in the same order of used variables in the string? It's clear for me now, i tried it and it does what i want it to do. Second, i don't think there's a shorter way to do it than this, so i'm gonna mark it as answered. :)

Comment: @Bart: The substitutions are patterned after a C standard function with the same name.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: If i understand it correctly, you're confirming what i asked in my comment?

Comment: @Bart: I'm really doubting that you can't find information on the web.  The first hit for "Matlab fprintf" is the official documentation, which explains them.  And even if you searched for just "fprintf" and found the C documentation, I'm letting you know that Matlab follows basically the same rules for the format string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following mini examples are helpful:

Example 1:

`a=42;
str1=sprintf('Value: %d',a);
disp(str1);`

Example 2:

`a=42;
str2=['Value: ' num2str(a)];
disp(str2);`